# Can I parse/compile a ChaiScript script once and invoke it many times?

Tags: compilation, evaluation, chaiscript

I'm trying to determine whether I can use ChaiScript but so far I'm very concerned that there doesn't seem to be a way to compile a script to use later. This would be a problem if a script has to be called hundreds of times per second, for example.

All the examples I've found refer to a C++ function called eval which takes an entire script as an argument and runs it.

So is it possible to separate the compile and run steps?

Comment: From experiments, it looks like I just use eval to request a reference to a function and then I can just invoke that function multiple times directly. Does that invoke the compiled code directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment:

> From experiments, it looks like I just use eval to request a reference to a function and then I can just invoke that function multiple times directly. Does that invoke the compiled code directly?

This is the best way to handle it. The `eval` will parse the code exactly once. When you take a `std::function` to the result and call that, you will be calling into your script the most efficient way you can.

Comment: Yeah, it works --- unfortunately, if there is a problem with the script, the exception handling mechanism, while catching an exception, provides zero useful information about the problem.

Comment: I stand corrected --- while fields like 'details' and 'filename' don't get filled in, pretty_print() does return useful info. Unfortunately, I'll have to pull the resulting string apart to get at the parts I need --- I don't want to just display that pretty_print error to the end user.

Comment: @David You actually have access to the entire call stack at the time of the error: https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/blob/develop/include/chaiscript/language/chaiscript_common.hpp#L111 but this is now far off topic for this stackoverflow question. I suggest you move the discussion to http://discourse.chaiscript.com

Comment: Thanks, I've created an account there and posted my other questions.